# How to avoid duplicating layout and style XML in various EditText fields?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I'm new in Android and i want learn more about layouts based on XML.

My problem is follow:

```
<EditText
    android:text="33"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="41dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
    android:id="@+id/math1"     />

<EditText...>
<EditText...>
<EditText...>
<EditText...>
<EditText...>
<EditText...>
<EditText...>
```

I want to edit all the "EditText" that appear in the code without applying controls to each.

Is there any way to do that?

I do not know if I explain. (Excuseme for my english, I am Chilean).

Comment: What do you mean by "Applying controls to each"? Do you have an Activity to host this layout yet?

Comment: I *think* he means: how to avoid duplicating the layout attributes for each EditText.

Comment: En español, que exactamente quisieras alcanzar? Puedo traducirlo.

Comment: Title clarified; should be reopened now.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is how to avoid duplicating layout attributes, you can use a `style`. For example:

In a `res/values/whatever.xml` file:

```
<style name="YourEditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">numberDecimal</item>
    <!-- and so on -->
</style>
```

Apply in layout xml:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/YourEditTextStyle"
    android:id="@+id/math1"
    .../>

<EditText
    style="@style/YourEditTextStyle"
    android:id="@+id/math2"

...
```

So when you need to modify the styling of your edittexts, you need to do it only once in the `style` resource.

Answer (score -2):

No, you have to access all the  EditText & set them manually !!